# How to use a system environment variable in init.gradle

Tags: environment-variables, gradle

We are migrating our builds over to gradle and I used to have an external script for deploying that referenced some system environment variables.  Am I able to reference them in my init.gradle and how do I access them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment variables are accessed in the usual Java way: `System.getenv()` to get all of them, and `System.getenv("foo")` to get a particular one.